# What're the _dotnet_bus_ exchanges used for while using Masstransit with RabbitMQ

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm using Masstransit with RabbitMQ as the event bus.

I followed the offical [quick start](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/quickstart.html) to setup a really simple demo. But after running the demo, I find that a couple of extra exchanges and queues are created in rabbitmq which named as "xxx**_dotnet_bus_**xxx". (BTW, those exchanges and queues are auto-deleted.)

[image: screenshot]

What are those "_dotnet_bus_" exchanges used for? How can I make use of them?

Comment: The very fact that they are auto deleted means that they are temporary queuues and exchanges created and used by masstransit for it's own operation. So you may not want to use them for the same reason. You should define your own exchanges and bindings based on your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but why masstransit needs those extra exchanges? I can't find any info about it.

Comment: At the end of the day Masstransit makes it easy for you to do asynchronous request response but it does use the Rabbit infrastructure to do so and for messaging work rabbit relies in exchanges , Bindings and queues. You can look up the source code of masstransit if you  really need to know.